# how can i populate objectId inside another objectId in mongoose

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I have an chatList and inside it there is messageId as an object id refer to Message Model , and that message model has messages array and inside it senderId as an objectId refer to User Model , in the User Controller i like to populate chatList.messageId.messages.senderId and i try but not working.

thats code i want it to work

```
.populate('chatList.messageId.messages.senderId')
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Follow this code**

```
> ref_id means model reference id

.populate("ref_id")
```

Comment: then you can again populate

Comment: the objectid's inside different model